# degree of exactness for a quadrature formula

Tags: integration, polynomials, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I sort of understand the intuition about the definition that if you have for example a constant function the you approximate the integral of the constant function with a first order polynomial, then the errors cancel out, therefore it has a degree of exactness one. But it would help me a lot if someone had an example which they could share so I can understand it better. Thank you!

**Definition:**
Let $[a,b]$ in $\Bbb R$ with $a < b$, and consider a quadrature formula:
$$
Q[f;a,b] = \sum_{k=0}^n w_k f(x_k)
$$
given in the terms of nodes $x_0 ,... ,x_n$ in $[a,b]$ with $x_0 < ... < x_n$ and weights $w_0, ... ,w_n$ in R. Then $Q$ is called exact of degree $m$ (in the natural numbers) if and only if for every basis $\{ p_0 , ..., p_m\}$ of $P_m$, we have:
$$
Q[p_j;a,b] = \int_a^b p_j(x) dx,~~~ j=0,....,m
$$

Comment: You should state the exact theorem that you have in mind.

Comment: @CarlChristian Apologies for that, I have now updated my question with the theorem.

Comment: No worries! Your definition is now clear to me, but you have not actually stated any theorem. It is not clear to me exactly what you would like to see.

Comment: @CarlChristian Ah you are right. I stated a definition instead of a theorem. I just need an example on how this definition actually works and how one could use this definition.

Comment: Am I right that the main problem is the fact that you must somehow manipulate all bases at once, rather than just a single specific basis?

Comment: Was the problem ultimately resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the key step is to recognize that it is enough to investigate a single basis for the space of polynomials of degree at most $m$, rather than every basis.

Specifically, if $\{p_j\}_{j=0}^m$ is a basis for $\mathbb{P}_m$ and
$$ \forall j \in \{0,1,2,\dotsc,m\} \: : \: Q(p) = \int_a^b p_j(x)dx,$$
then we automatically have
$$ \forall p \in \mathbb{P}_m \: : \: Q(p) = \int_a^b p(x)dx = I(p).$$
This follows from the linearity of $Q$, i.e., if $$p(x) = \sum_{j=0}^m r_j p_j(x),$$ then
$$ Q(p) = Q\left(\sum_{j=0}^m r_j p_j\right) = \sum_{j=0}^m r_j Q(p_j) = \sum_{j=0}^m r_j \int_a^b p_j(x)dx = \int_a^b \sum_{j=0}^m r_j p_j(x)dx = \int_a^b p(x)dx.$$
In short, there is no need to examine more than a single basis.

As a specific example, we consider the simple trapezoidal rule on the interval $I_h = [-h,h]$. Here $Q$ is the simple rule given by
$$Q(f) = h (f(-h) + f(h)).$$
We choose $p_j : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be the polynomial given by $p_j(x) = x^j$. Then $$Q(p_0) = 2h, \quad Q(p_1) = 0, \quad Q(p_2) = 2h^3$$ and the integrals are $$I(p_0) = 2h, \quad I(p_1) = 0, \quad I(p_2) = \frac{2}{3} h^3.$$
We see that the trapezoidal rule is exact for all polynomials of degree at most 1. It follows that the degree of exactness is $m=1$.